# PushManager subscription fails on Firefox for Android

Tags: javascript, firefox, push-notification, service-worker, firefox-android

I'm working on integrating web-push notifications in my web-application. Everything works fine for Chrome and Firefox on desktop and Chrome on Android, but not for **Firefox for Android**. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63738057/firefox-pushmanager-subscribe-does-not-work-on-android) seems to discuss the same issue but has no responses.

I used [this tutorial](https://suryasankar.medium.com/how-to-setup-basic-web-push-notification-functionality-using-a-flask-backend-1251a5413bbe#7323) as a base for the service worker registration script. I have added some more prints/checks but it is mostly the same.

So, when calling the `registerServiceWorker` method from a button press on FF Android, the `serviceWorker` is installed, the `subscribeUser` function is called, but the `pushManager.subscribe` method will fail with the following error message:

```
DOMException: User denied permission to use the Push API.
```

This is not correct, even while paused on the error print line `Notification.permission` will return `"granted"`.

Doing the same thing on the *nightly build* results in slightly different, but still incorrect behaviour. The `pushManager.subscribe` method does not throw an error. Instead the callback is ran but with a `null` value for the `subscription` argument. Therefore, the process still fails.

Service worker registration script:

```js
'use strict';

function updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription, apiEndpoint) {
  return fetch(apiEndpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      subscription_json: JSON.stringify(subscription)
    })
  });

}

function subscribeUser(swRegistration, applicationServerPublicKey, apiEndpoint) {
  // It seems browsers can take the base64 string directly.
  // const applicationServerKey = urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey);
  console.log(`Subscribing pushManager with appkey ${applicationServerPublicKey}`);
  swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: applicationServerPublicKey
  })
  .then(function(subscription) {
    console.log('User is subscribed.');
    console.log(`Sending subscription data to server (${apiEndpoint})`, subscription);

    return updateSubscriptionOnServer(subscription, apiEndpoint);

  })
  .then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Bad status code from server.');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(responseData) {
    console.log(responseData);
    if (responseData.status!=="success") {
      throw new Error('Bad response from server.');
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // FF Android says "User denied permission to use the Push API."
    console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);
    console.log(err.stack);
  });
}

function registerServiceWorker(serviceWorkerUrl, applicationServerPublicKey, apiEndpoint){
  let swRegistration = null;
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
    console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');
    console.log(`Current Notification.permission = ${Notification.permission}`);

    swRegistration = navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
    .then(function(swReg) {
      console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);
      console.log(`Current Notification.permission = ${Notification.permission}`); // Will give "granted"
      subscribeUser(swReg, applicationServerPublicKey, apiEndpoint);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
    });
  } else {
    console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
    return false;
  }
  return swRegistration;
}
```

I cannot figure out how to get a working push-subscription. As said before, all other browsers that I have tried work fine. I hope someone can point me in the right direction. Is this a bug in Firefox Android or in my code?

Showing notifications manually using

```js
new Notification("Hi there!");
```

does work, proving in principle that permissions are not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: **This issue is still on**. Feel free check the progress on
Bugzilla :

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1807379

UPDATE:
FF Fenix team confirmed a **bug** while displaying the notifications

Feel free to track it [here](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/19152)

Got curious regarding service worker support for Firefox mobile browser.
Tried hard to find a debug tool for Mobile Firefox as plugin or a 3rd party tool with no luck.

However, I've tested my web push application on Mobile Firefox and may totally confirm there is an issue with **Service Worker Registration state**.

In order to discard any issues within my code, I've used [Matt Gaunt's Webpush Book](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/)

And I can tell Matt's service worker returns registration as simply as that:

```
 async function registerSW() {
  await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/demos/notification-examples/service-worker.js');
}

function getSW() {
  return navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('/demos/notification-examples/service-worker.js');
}
```

Firefox for Android successfully requests permission for notification, **but it doesn't display push whenever you launch the .showNotification function**.

Here's an example of showNotification method within the Badge example in Matt's website:

```
 async function onBadgeClick() {
            const reg = await getSW();
            /**** START badgeNotification ****/
            const title = 'Badge Notification';
            const options = {
                badge: '/demos/notification-examples/images/badge-128x128.png'
            };
            reg.showNotification(title, options);
            /**** END badgeNotification ****/
        }
```

**Looks fine and should be working fine, but for Firefox Mobile it doesn't work at all**.
I guess this issue should be escalated to Mozilla.

**UPDATE**
New bug report was created on Github:

Comment: Hey - I'm wondering if you ever ended up escalating this to Firefox? Is there an issue on their tracker?

Comment: Not yet, since I'm using ADB manager to prepare a sophisticated description of the issue. Hopefully, I will succeed with posting. Current build 88.1.1 is still experiencing issues with displaying notification.